# Using enumeration type value in Core Data Entity

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

How to use enumeration type value in Core Data Entity attribute? except choosing transformable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't store the enumeration type directly, because Core Data doesn't understand Swift enums. You'll need to declare the enumeration to have a raw value of some kind, and save the raw value in Core Data. Something like

```
enum Bar : Int {
    case bar1;
    case bar2;
}

let myBar = Bar.bar1

// Then save myBar.rawValue in Core Data as an integer type
```

When reading, get the integer value from Core Data and convert it to the enumeration as

```
let rawValue = managedObject.bar
let value = Bar(rawValue: rawValue)
```